# my ajax request keep getting failed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using keyup function to get sponsor name from sponsor id inputusing below ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sponsor").change(function(){
        var sponsorID= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { sponsorID: sponsorID},
            url: "<?php echo base_url('site/getsponsorName');?>",
            success: function(){
                alert('success');
              },
              error: function(){
                alert('failure');
              }
        });
    });
});
```

and this is my function :

```
public function getsponsorName(){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('sponsorID'));
    $qr = $this->db->get('user');
    $res = $qr->row(); //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$res->name');</script>";
        echo $res->name;
}
```

I am getting error each time.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? We need to see that to pinpoint the issue..

Comment: each time code alerts failure only

Comment: Rewrite `error: function(){` as `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){` and within `error:function`, do a `console.log(errorThrown)`. You will see the error for yourself.

Comment: Yo also might need to learn more on `jQuery.ajax`. Refer the [jQuery documentation on `jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: thanks @RomeoSierra i am getting 403 forbidden

Comment: That means you are sending the request to a restricted location. You need to check the URL that you are contacting with this request.

Comment: calling a function from controllers file which have 777 permissions, can't figure out it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174308/discussion-between-romeo-sierra-and-techansaari).